# RegEx to remove DOT

Tags: regex, regular-language

I want to remove dot (.) but I don't know how can I write this pattern.

I have some text line this.

> E-1-2-3.1-0-0 or E-1-2-0-2.5-0 or E-1-2-0-3.5-0

But in my text some are numbers like 2.5, 56.7. I don't want to remove these dots are they are decimals.

Just if in lines then I need to remove dot. `-5.2-` will be `-52-`

`E-1-2-3.1-0-0` will `E-1-2-31-0-0`
`E-1-2-0-2.5-0` will `E-1-2-0-25-0`
`E-1-2-0-3.5-0` will `E-1-2-0-35-0`

There can inside has DOT or NOT.

Any help regarding this pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to match dots surrounded by dash-digit and digit-dash, try positive lookarounds:

```
(?<=-\d)\.(?=\d-)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nY7fA9/1

---

If you need to match dots surrounded by dash-digits and digits-dash (any positive number of digits), the thing is more tricky since lookbehinds do not support quantifiers in many regex flavors. In this case you may match the prefix with a normal regex and immediately reset the match with `\K`:

```
-\d+\K\.(?=\d+-)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nY7fA9/2

Comment: Thank you answer .

But if numbers will change not catching them . For example , E-1-2-53.1-0-0 or E-1-2-0-35862.5-0 or E-1-2-0-23.5-0

How can we this catch all beetwen -.....- any numbers with dot